# Do I cut down Broad Beans after Harvesting?

Tags: vegetables, harvesting, food-crops, fava-beans

I am growing Broad beans of the aquadulce variety. After I have harvested the beans and the weather has become too cold and dark for the plant to make new pods, should I cut them down and plant something else? Or can I leave them in the ground and get more beans next Summer? What will happen if I leave the plants up?

Comment: Probably cut them down, but the possibility of multi-year production depends both on whether the plant even does that AND where you are. My tomatoes die if left in the garden due to Winter. I've seen a 4-5 year old tomato plant grown to the size of a small tree in the tropics - that one had been "since the last hurricane"  according to locals, so suitable tomatoes could go on for even longer without winter or severe hurricane hits. I have no idea if broad beans would, though. But if you get much winter, probably not.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Yes whether the plant can make more beans in the second year period is my question. I presume they will be fine for the Winter. They sprouted in January when it was still cold. So I guess I'll leave them and find out.